# Android LinearLayout Multi-Touch

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view, multi-touch

I am using `LinearLayout`'s to represent different parts of my UI.  The idea is that these layouts will be in a grid arrangement.  In addition, the user will be able to drag the windows around to re-arrange them.  I started by creating my layouts, and everything works great.  Then I applied an `OnTouchListener` to my views:

```
 touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.e("VARS","MotionEvent!");
                if(event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                Log.e("VARS","It's two!");

                }
                return false;
            }
        };
```

It completely ignores the case where `event.getPointerCount()` is two!  It seems that this method is only invoked when the pointer count is one.  I put this in my manifest:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>`

and it still doesn't work.  Does `LinearLayout` have a special case where only `MotionEvent`'s with a pointer count of one are recognized, or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `return false` to `return true`.  By consuming the `MotionEvent`, it will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerCount%28%29

You cannot set it higher than 1.
It doesnt have something to do with linearlayout.

Comment: The documentation says "always >= 1", which means "greater than or equal to one."

Comment: Also, I'm not "setting" anything - I'm reading the data from `MotionEvent`.